# ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch: User(#70180695416600) expected, got Hash(#70180672006440)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rspec-rails

I am test driving a social networking app on ROR

I will let the code speak for itself:

User.rb:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  has_many :friendships, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :inverse_friendships, class_name: "Friendship", foreign_key: "friend_id", dependent: :destroy

  def request_friendship(user_2)
    self.friendships.create(friend: user_2)
  end
end
```

Friendship.rb:

```
class Friendship < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :friend, class_name: "User"

  def accept_friendship
    self.update_attributes(state: "active", friended_at: Time.now)
  end

  def deny_friendship
    self.destroy
  end

  def cancel_friendship
    self.destroy
  end
end
```

and my User model test..
user_spec.rb:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe User, :type => :model do
  let!(:user1) { User.create(email: 'test_user1@example.com', password: 'testtest', password_confirmation: 'testtest') }
  let!(:user2) { User.create(email: 'test_user2@example.com', password: 'testtest', password_confirmation: 'testtest') }

  it "new user has no friendships" do
    expect(user1.friendships.length).to eq 0
  end

  it "can add another user as a friend" do
    user2 = User.create(email: 'test_user2@example.com', password: 'testtest', password_confirmation: 'testtest')
    user1.request_friendship(friend: user2)
    expect(user1.friendships.length).to eq 1
  end
end
```

When I run this test I get the following error:

```
2) User can add another user as a friend
     Failure/Error: self.friendships.create(friend: user_2)

     ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch:
       User(#70180695416600) expected, got Hash(#70180672006440)
     # ./app/models/user.rb:11:in `request_friendship'
     # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:13:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

I wish I could give more details but the code is fairly basic and I am just not sure how to test the .request_friendship method on my User model.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
user1.request_friendship(friend: user2)
```

In this line with `friend: user2` you are passing n hash, this hash

```
{ :friend => user2 }
```

but that method expects a user. So

```
user1.request_friendship(user2)
```

Comment: Genius， thank you! Yet another situation where all that syntactic sugar has come back to haunt me